# Сворачивание блока добавленного делегированным событием

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список дел, сами дела добавляются с помощью делегированного события, нужно реализовать сворачивание блока, но чтобы заголовок было видно, не могу понять как сделать правильно. Добавлю строки из кода:
Сворачивание блока

```
Сворачивание блока:
caseListEl.on('click', '.js-hide', function() {
const list = $('.js-container').find('.case-text');
list.slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const list = $(this).closest('.js-container').find('.case-text');
```